# Database First with EF6 / Mysql added Schema name X.X.Y

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6

I create a edmx model from Database.

When I'm trying to use my model, i get this error:

[image]

I have try many search, but didn't find any solution.
Why there is cans.cans before the name of my table? one is the database name, but the other is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Bug in the version 8.0.22 of MySql.Data.EntityFramework

Downgrade to 8.0.21 and I think your problem will be solved.